# Get the character codes from a varchar2

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the correct/best way of getting the character codes from a `varchar2` in Oracle?

I want a function that accepts a `varchar2` as the parameter and will return a sequence of bytes which are the character codes of the characters in the `varchar2` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`dump` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm):

```
select dump('Hello world') from dual;

DUMP('HELLOWORLD')                                     
--------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=11: 72,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100
```

Or in hex:

```
select dump('Hello world', 1016) from dual;

DUMP('HELLOWORLD',1016)                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=11 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 48,65,6c,6c,6f,20,77,6f,72,6c,64
```

If you want the RAW equivalent of the string you can use [the `utl_i18n.string_to_raw` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71164):

```
select utl_i18n.string_to_raw('Hello world') from dual;

UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('HELLOWORLD')                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
48656C6C6F20776F726C64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION toAscii(s IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    r VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH(s) LOOP
        r := r||TO_CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTR(s, i, 1)), 'FMXX');
    END LOOP;
    RETURN r;
END toAscii;
/

SELECT toAscii('ABCxyz') FROM DUAL;
41424378797A
```

Comment: Which is the same answer you get from the built-in `select utl_i18n.string_to_raw('ABCxyz') from dual;`